# Why am I getting an object required error in this VBA code

Tags: vba

The error seems to occur at the start of the for loop, here is the code

```
Sub constructContractScurves(contractCollection As Collection)

    Dim xArray() As Variant
    Dim yArray() As Variant
    Dim ans As Boolean
    Dim contract As CContract

    For Each contract In contractCollection
        xArray = constructXarray(contract.numMonths)
        yArray = constructYarray(xArray, contract.numMonths)
        ans = utilityMod.populateSheet(xArray, yArray, "S-Curve-BW", 49, 7)
    Next contract
End Sub
```

Comment: On the for or the xarray line?

Comment: The collection object in VBA is pretty limited. In this case it will not be an enumerable collection of CContract objects so For Each will not work. Use a counter instead.

Comment: Or declare contract as variant.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your replies, they are appreciated. The problem was that the function that called this sub had the instantiation of the collection in an if statement, so if the condition was not met the collection was not made an instance. When I took it out of the if statement, the code compiled successfully.

Thanks